# How can I remove special characters from my column

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, alphanumeric

Have a table with 2 columns. Column a has records with non alpha such as:

```
aaa)
aab(
aac#
123!
```

column b is blank

Need a PostgreSQL function that can strip all non alpha characters and insert the changed values to column b.

So that the end result is

columna

```
aaa)
aab(
aac#
123!
```

columnb

```
aaa
aab
aac
123
```

I want to be able to call function with table name. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` :

```
UPDATE YourTable t
set t.columnB = regexp_replace(t.columnA, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', 'g')
```

This should update your table `columnB` with the content of `columnA` without the special characters

Comment: Thanks. But i get an error when i try this.  ERROR: column "t" of relation "test_clean" does not exist

Comment: Please post the query you'd made, I think you didn't write the aliases good. @JayParker This query should work.

Comment: UPDATE public.test_clean t
set t.new_param = regexp_replace(t.old_param, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', 'g');

Comment: ERROR:  column "t" of relation "test_clean" does not exist
LINE 2: set t.new_param = regexp_replace(t.old_param, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'...
            ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "t" of relation "test_clean" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 34

Comment: got it to work. thanks, but i need this in a function where i can pass in tbl